# Django two inner joins

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am new in Django. I have an mySQL query:

```
    SELECT username, foto FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (a.user_id = b.id) INNER JOIN c ON (a.foto_id = c.id)
```

How to write it in Django?

models:

```
    class b(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class c(models.Model):
        user_id = models.IntegerField()
        foto = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class a(models.Model):
        user_id = models.IntegerField()
        foto = models.ForeignKey('c', blank=True, null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: I think this will be easier if you show your models.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [select_related()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-which-fields-may-be-ordered-against):

```
A.objects.select_related('b', 'c').values('b__username', 'c__foto')
```